# Java: How to disable a button in java?

Tags: java, swing, button

I want to automatically disable a few buttons.
I wrote the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public int[] zamrozone = new int[4];

a1 = new JButton("A1");
a2 = new JButton("A2");
a3 = new JButton("A2");
a4 = new JButton("A2");
a5 = new JButton("A2");

   private void zamroz()
    {

        zamrozone[0]=1;
        zamrozone[1]=1;
        zamrozone[2]=1;
        zamrozone[3]=0;
        zamrozone[4]=0;

        for(int i=0; i<8; i++) //losuje 8 statkow
            {
                if(zamrozone[i]==1)
                   "a"+i.setEnabled(false); // here is an error
            }
    }
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: remove the `"a"+` and in place of `i.setEnabled(false);` use your button declarations... e.g.: `a1.setEnabled(false);`

You won't be able to dynamically call your variable names in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the JButtons in an array and then use their index:

```
import javax.swing.*;

final int SIZE = 5;

JButton[] buttons = new JButton[SIZE]
for (int i=0; i<SIZE;i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton("A" + i)
}

public int[] zamrozone = new int[SIZE];

private void zamroz()
{ 
    zamrozone[0]=1;
    zamrozone[1]=1;
    zamrozone[2]=1;
    zamrozone[3]=0;
    zamrozone[4]=0;

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) //losuje SIZE statkow
    {
        if (zamrozone[i]==1) {
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false); // here is an error
        }
     }
     :
}
```

Use defined SIZE rather then constant values all over your code to avoid OutOfBounds exception and make the code easier to change/maintain.

Answer (score 0):

`"a"+i.setEnabled(false);` cannot work as variables don't work that way. What you are doing right there is trying to call `setEnabled` on the integer `i` and then adding the return value (which does not exist as `setEnabled` returns `void`) to the String literal "a".

I would suggest storing your buttons in an array as well and then simply calling `buttonArray[i].setEnabled(false)` inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.
I did it like you said,but it still not working.
 `zamrozone[is].setEnabled(false);`
error code:

`cannot find symbol
symbol: method setEnabled(boolean)
location: class String`

Comment: `zamrozone` is your *integer-array*. You need to create a new array that contains the buttons, like `JButton[] buttonArray = new JButton[5]`. On that note, `zamrozone` will also need to be a `int[5]` rather than an `int[4]` or else you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when setting values. Also make to change your loop to `for(int i=0; i<zamrozone.length; i++)` to avoid the same exception.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I get down to work. Thanks a lot!